# How to restore Mac default python after Installing another python using Homebrew?

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I tried to move away from Mac default version of python, but for various reasons that doesn't suit me well so I want to revert it back.

What I did:
I followed http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x#p1

to first install homebrew, then installed python.

This screwed me up because I execute a python script I used to be able to run with default python, I got:

==================================================

Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so

==================================================

I can feel the messed up version because:

---

$ which python

/usr/local/bin/python

---

and

---

$ python

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

---

[this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Expected%20in%3A%20flat%20namespace%20in%20%2Fusr%2Flocal%2FCellar%2Fpython%2F2.7.12_2%2FFrameworks%2FPython.framework%2FVersions%2F2.7%2Flib%2Fpython2.7%2Flib-dynload%2F_io.so&oq=Expected%20in%3A%20flat%20namespace%20in%20%2Fusr%2Flocal%2FCellar%2Fpython%2F2.7.12_2%2FFrameworks%2FPython.framework%2FVersions%2F2.7%2Flib%2Fpython2.7%2Flib-dynload%2F_io.so&aqs=chrome..69i57.977j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) didn't feel helpful

Answer (score 2):

Simply did:

$ rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/python

(and $ brew cleanup) (not sure whether that's necessary)
also brew uninstall python doesn't work so..

Comment: Well I should say it didnt completely work for me, I found pip was missing afterwards I needed to then run sudo easy_install pip